# Flex: Does [Bindable] properties, methods, events consuming more CPU or Memory than the normal ones?

Tags: apache-flex

A question is worried me past few days - I have build all my classes with a lot of properties which is [Bindable], and just to be sure i wish to ask :

- Does [Bindable] properties, methods, events consuming more CPU or Memory than the normal ones ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes, definitely yes.

Under the hood, mxmlc (flex compiler) creates getter/setter for this property, which dispatches events (propertyChangeEvent) on each property change. These events make data binding tick.

So, [Bindable] makes

- classes bigger (they consume more memory)
- accessing properties slower (it's now a getter method)
- setting properties much slower, because on each change an event is dispatched, which gets handled by all the other components, that bind to this property.

If you're really worried about the performance, then you should consider using [Bindable] wisely.

Comment: :| This is what i were worry of. Thanks.

Comment: This is all true. On the other hand, it will be rare that Bindable properties actually affect performance in any way that you will be able to see. Don't worry about it unless you're app is running slow due to many, many, many bindings updating all at once.